# problem at refresh report viewer

Tags: c#, winforms, refresh, reportviewer

HY! I have a WinForm application and I use report viewer. I have in my form 2 dateTimePickers and I have the problem when I change those values, my report does not change. I know what should be displayed because if I put the second values first it shows me result.
Ex: dateTimePicker1 = 01.01.2011
dateTimePicker2 = 03.01.2011
i have displyad in my reportviewer name1, name2,name3
If I change dateTimePicker2 = 05.01.2011 I should see name4, name5 too, but i do not see them
If I exit the form and run again and I put the values dateTimePicker1 = 01.01.2011, dateTimePicker2 = 03.01.2011  I see all the 5 names, but if I switch again  dateTimePicker2 = 03.01.2011   , name4 and name5 does not disappear.
I put reportViewer.Refresh(), but does not work.
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when the date is changed your app is then changing whatever parameter you are passing to your report viewer to reflect the new date.

Another thing you can do is run a trace on the database using SQL Profiler to see exactly what the SQL is that your app is sending to the database. Make sure that part is correct. If it isn't what you expect, you can work on fixing it and finding out why the app is putting together the wrong query. If it is what you expect, then check to make sure the database is returning what you expect from that query.

Comment: It changes. If I debug my code it seems to be ok, but when my form appear it is not showing what I saw at debugging  and I don`t know where is the problem